# JSON parsing issue in tabs and list View

Tags: mysql, json, android-volley

I am parsing my mysql data base from free hosting, and trying to display its json feed into the list view. 
here's my function which is performing that task. The problem i am facing is that, after i create the Json object, my data or the json feed data doesn't reach the if statement and the for loop.
Also im using volley.

```
 private void getNews() {
    Log.d("MD","In News");
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"http://informerasad.3eeweb.com/services/query.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            if(s!=null)
            {
                Log.d("MD",s);
                try {
                    Log.d("try part","called");

                    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(s);
                    String status=obj.getString("status");
                    if(status.equals("true")) {
                        Log.d("status", "Is true");

                        JSONArray array=obj.getJSONArray("news_data");
                       // int i = array.length();
                        Log.d("array length", "" + array.length());

                       for (int i = 0; i <= array.length(); i++){
                            Log.d("Inside loop", "In Loop");
                            JSONObject jObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            ListModel model = new ListModel();
                            model.setCompanyName(jObj.getString("News_Title"));
                            model.setDesc(jObj.getString("News_Description"));
                            model.setImage(jObj.getString("News_Img"));
```

//                                CustomListViewValuesArr.add(model);
                                CustomListViewValuesArr.add(model);

```
                            list.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
```

and in log cat, Inside loop log statement doesnt show..
what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this piece of code would help us to know where u stuck at but first thing first try to debug it and see if there's data in your ArrayList 's list or not. you can also do this by printing the size of your list after the for loop.